# Premiere Pro plays media video stream at half the speed as audio

Tags: premiere, bug

In Premiere Pro 2020 (14.7), some media files have video playing at half the speed as the source, either in the source monitor or the timeline. Here is one example in Premiere with a still apparently at minute 6:

[image: Premiere Pro]

Here is the source file playing in VLC showing a near still at minute 3:

[image: VLC]

The same problem appears in [this thread](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/video-playback-at-half-speed-while-audio-remains-normal-pp-13-0-3/td-p/10419614). The solution there was to re-open the project, which didn't work for me, and neither did restarting Premiere.

I have this issue whether I set ingest to create proxies or not.

How can I fix this issue?

**Update**: This is an issue with Adobe After Effects 2020 as well, so most likely an issue with some basic code in the 2020 version. I used a clip in Premiere 2019 and in After Effects 2020 from about 0:30 (shown in the first picture as marked in and out). After Effects rendered the video at half the speed and showing frames that are at 0:14 in the original footage. Lucky for me, I didn't need the audio for that clip in After Effects 2020.

[image: original footage in Premiere 2019]

[image: rendered footage in After Effects 2020]

Answer (score 0):

I spent 5 hours with Adobe support and an engineer, where we tried cleaning the media cache, removing preference files, removing "Application Support" files, rendering in to out, and downgrading from 14.7 to 14.3. The issue still persisted. Adobe said it was my fault because I have the minimum 8 GB of RAM instead of the recommended 16 GB. It sounds like a bug to me.

I tried the oldest version of Premiere, 13.1.5 without creating proxies when ingesting, and it did not have that problem.